# Wild card search in Java strings

Tags: java, string, wildcard

Hi I have a list of Strings..

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Test");
list.add("Test Test");
list.add("Test Second");
```

I want to search string like "Te*"..

I used the following code for searching

```
queryString = "Te*";
    queryString = queryString.replaceAll("\\*", "\\\\w*");
    for (String str : values) {
            if (str.matches(queryStr) || str.contains(queryStr))
                list.add(str);
    }
```

This piece of code returning only 'Test'.. but not "Test Test"..

If element having spaces , then this code is not working

Comment: What is the purpose of the second line? You can set its value in assignment. Te\w*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am by no means a regex expert. But not replacing the * at all, and adding a .* at the end did it for me

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Test");
        list.add("Test Test");
        list.add("Test Second");
        String queryString = "Te*s";
//      queryString = queryString.replaceAll("\\*", "\\.\\*");
        queryString = queryString.concat(".*");
        for (String str : list) {
                if (str.matches(queryString))
                    System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're replacing your * to \w* which means find "word characters" until you can, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) try replacing it `.*` that should do the trick and you could also get rid of those ugly escapes :) Also you could use java8 stream api to make it look nicer like this:

```
List<String> list = values.stream().filter( s -> s.matches(queryStr)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code works:

```
String queryStr = "Te.*";
for (String str : list) {
    if (str.matches(queryStr))
        values.add(str);
}
System.out.println(values);
```

The first issue was that `matches()` matches complete string, so you had to update regexp. `\w` will match word and if there is space than it is another word. This in conjuction with `matches()` caused that it will never work. I modified the regexp so it will match all strings starting with `Te`, because `.*` will match everything else.

There was another bug, that you were trying to iterate over `str` list and then add found element into the same list. Java would throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues

1. `matches` only returns true for a full-string match, not a sub-string match
2. `\w` only matches word characters not spaces.
3. `contains` finds literal sub-string matches, not regular expressions.

Your solution is either:

1. Replace your query string with one that actually matches what you want to match - probably you want to change it to use `.replaceAll("\\*", ".*")`
2. Use `Pattern.find` instead of `String.match`

Answer (score 0):

Try with Pattern.quote.

```
yourString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("Te"),"");
```

Here it is replacing all "Te" by "";